# почему контейнер с БД падает?

Tags: mysql, docker, wsl2

И так, я продолжаю предпринимать попытки вкатиться в докер. На этот раз возникли трудности с БД, а именно с контейнером, в docker-compose.yml он выглядит так и на windows всё работает исправно:

```
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laradoc
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root 
    ports:
      - 8228:3306
    command: --lower_case_table_names=2 mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci 
    container_name: project_db
```

но я пытаюсь начать проект на laravel, а потому мне приходится переносить проект на linux, делаю это я с помощью wsl2. И вот тут уже начинаются проблемы, потому как после того, как я поднимаю контейнер, контейнер с базой работает пару секунд и падает. Вот, собственно его логи:

2023-05-28 22:14:35 2023-05-28T18:14:35.694565Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011087] [Server] Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('0') and data dictionary ('2').

2023-05-28 22:14:35 2023-05-28T18:14:35.694778Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.

2023-05-28 22:14:35 2023-05-28T18:14:35.694822Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

Из них я понял, что настройки регистра имен таблиц для сервера MySQL и словаря данных не совпадают. Нашёл в интернете несколько вариантов, таких как например вручную включить регистрозависимость в папке ./tmp/db с помощью команды fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo ./ enable или прописать command: --lower_case_table_names=2, но все они не сработали.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я могу сделать со всем этим. С меня как обычно огромное спасибо.

UPD: сейчас заметил, что контейнер падает и на windows так же, вчера всё работало нормально, понятия не имею, что успело случиться.

UPD#2: после выполнения этой команды fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo ./ disable в папке tmp\db\ на windows контейнер падать снова перестал.

UPD#3: спустя ещё день почти разбил лицо facepalm'ом, когда просто создал проект сразу на linux и всё заработало. (учился по какому-то гайду с ютуба 2-х годовалой давности и там разбирали эту тему именно создавая проект сначала на windows, при этом на видео всё работало), почему я не сделал этого сразу? В общем, проблема решена, всем спасибо за внимание.

Comment: а откуда вообще у вас эти танцы с бубном вокруг регистрозависимости? Всегда называйте БД и таблицы в нижнем регистре и проблем не будет никаких.

Comment: @teran а при чем здесь это? У меня контейнер падает, ещё нет никаки таблиц, проблема в разных настройках, которые я почему-то изменить не могу при переносе проекта с windows на linux

Comment: Вы перенесли файлы базы данных из `./tmp/db`?

Comment: @PakUula да, я скопировал всю папку с проектом из Windows на Linux с помощью консольной команды cp -r /mnt/c/path/to/source/folder /path/to/destination/folder

Comment: У вас какие-то грандиозные траблы с регистром имён файлов. Я бы предложил вам хранить базу данных в разделе WSL2, а не в Windows. Тогда при переносе кодировка таблиц и индексов в файловой системе не будет меняться. И ещё, я бы не стал использовать `--lower_case_table_names=2`, а оставил бы значение по-умолчанию.

Comment: @PakUula да, спасибо, я так и поступил, просто создал проект вместе с базой и всем остальным сразу на wsl2, не понимаю почему я не сделал этого раньше, теперь всё работает как и должно